# Como ir sustituyendo una cantida de ceros? JS

Tags: javascript

Estoy haciendo un pequeño juego, y para implementar los puntos estoy pensando en inicializarlo así: 00000, cada enemigo que vaya eliminando se le va agregando el valor, pero comenzaría de atrás hacia adelante, es decir, elimino a un enemigo que da 5 pts, sería 00005, elimino otro, 00010, es decir que se le vaya sumando a los dígitos de atrás, no pongo código porque de verdad no tengo idea de como comenzarlo.

Comment: Vaya, sin código no podemos ayudarte, en todo caso, lo que mostrarás será siempre un valor de cadena. Aunque el puntaje sea numérico. Te recomiendo leer [`padStart`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/padStart) del Objeto `String`. Saludos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podrías concatenar los valores después de realizar la suma de puntos y devolver tus puntos con los cuatro dígitos en formato cadena.
Algo si :

```js
function mifunction(valor) {
  let puntos=0;
  let resultado='';
  puntos=puntos+valor;
  
  if(puntos.toString().length==1){
    resultado='000'+puntos.toString();
  }else if(puntos.toString().length==2){
    resultado='00'+puntos.toString();
  }else if(puntos.toString().length==3){
    resultado='0'+puntos.toString();
  }else {
    resultado=puntos.toString();
  }
  
  return resultado;
}
    
console.log(mifunction(1));
console.log(mifunction(12));
console.log(mifunction(123));
console.log(mifunction(1234));
```

Comment: Gracias por responder, pero en el futuro debes evitar responder preguntas que no muestran un [mcve]. De lo contrario da la sensación que haces el trabajo de los demás. Saludos

Comment: Entiendo, pero el aclaro que no podía el código porque no tenia idea de como empezarlo, y creo yo  que también es valida la ayuda.

Comment: No niego que tu ayuda sea válida, pero debemos evitar responder preguntas mal formuladas. Es cuestión de apegarse a las normas. Saludos

Comment: @Santiago muchas gracias por la respuesta amigo, aunque ya lo hice con la de maurio, usando el metodo padStart

Comment: @plus No hay problema amigo, Saludos

Answer (score 1):

Aunque la respuesta de Santiago funciona, dejo aqui mi forma de hacerlo que es mas limpia que usar "if-else" que es en si mismo una mala práctica.

```js
let puntuacionInicial = 0;
const longitudPuntuacion = 5;
document.getElementById("puntuacion").value = "00000";

function eliminarEnemigo() {
  let puntuacion = document.getElementById("puntuacion").value;
  puntuacion = parseInt(puntuacion) + 5;
  
  var cerosParaCompletar = longitudPuntuacion - puntuacion.toString().length;
  
  document.getElementById("puntuacion").value = "0".repeat(cerosParaCompletar) + puntuacion
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <label for="puntuacion">Puntuacion: </label>
    <input id="puntuacion" type="text" readonly>
    <button onClick="eliminarEnemigo()">Eliminar enemigo</button>
  </body>
</html>
```